# copying data from one data frame to other using variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to transfer data from one data frame to other. I want to copy all 8 columns from a huge data frame to a smaller one and name the columns n1, n2, etc..

first I am trying to find the column number from which I need to copy by using this

```
x=as.numeric(which(colnames(old_df)=='N1_data'))
```

Then I am pasting it in new data frame this way

```
new_df[paste('N',1:8,'new',sep='')]=old_df[x:x+7]
```

However, when I run this, all the new 8 columns have exactly same data. However, instead if I directly use the value of x, then I get what I want like

```
new_df[paste('N',1:8,'new',sep='')]=old_df[10:17]
```

So my questions are

- Why I am not able to use the variable x. I added as.numeric just to make sure it is a number not a list. However, that does not seem to help.
- Is there any better or more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: `x=10; old_df[x:(x+7)]`? Because `x:x+7` is `17`, not `10:17`.

Comment: Thanks. That was silly I guess but I could not find any way to find this on my own without asking.  Is the downvote because it is not a 'useful' question?

Comment: I didn't give the downvote, but my guess is that someone downvoted because the question is pretty basic and has been asked many times. IMO there's nothing wrong with being a beginner and asking questions where you genuinely seem stuck, which you were.

Comment: Yes and thanks again! I tried to search previous post but could not figure out right key words to search for this problem. Also, same syntax i.e. without parenthesis would work in other language, for instance MATLAB. As you pointed out, I am a beginner and trying to learn R and realizing I need to do lot of MATLAB unlearning as well..!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you may be overthinking the problem.

```
library(dplyr);
new_df <- select(old_df, N1_data, N2_data, N3_data, N4_data,
                         N5_data, N6_data, N7_data, N8_data);

colnames(new_df) <- sub("N(\\d)_data", "n\\\\1", colnames(new_df));
```

Comment: @Laterows's answer was exactly what was my problem. However, interesting suggestion from you as well and good to learn something new.